# Using a thread with designer objects vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, performance, antivirus

I have a big problem. I am currently designing an Antivirus, and it is coming along very well. But having all the scanning engines running on the same thread, I.E. the main one, is causing the app to lag in loading, and to become unresponsive during processes. I have tried implementing multithreading to increase the speed and overall performance of my application. But, every time that I try, i get the error of cross threading, I.E. I cannot use the form designers progress bars, buttons and labels etc. I just want to know why this error is thrown up, and how to fix it.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use InvokeRequired to check which thread you are calling from, if you're not in the UI thread then InvokeRequired is True, and so you can invoke a delegate from the UI Thread to safely alter the Control:

```
    Public Sub SetText(ByVal text As String)
        If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
            'Invoke a delegate from the UI Thread
            Me.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() Label1.Text = "Test", MethodInvoker))
        Else
            Button1.Text = text
        End If
    End Sub
```

It is unsafe to call a control from a thread other than the one that created the control without using the Invoke method. Take a look at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms171728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't understand how the invoke method works, could you please provide a VB.NET code sample that works and tell me in more detail how it works

Comment: `Me.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() Label1.Text = "Test", MethodInvoker))`  Where "Label1.Text = "Test"" stands, you can use functions/methodes, too.

Comment: Thanks that code actually helped A LOT! Now I can make my Anti-Virus multithreaded, and get it running faster and more reliably! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set your form property: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to false. The you are getting no errors any more.

Furthermore you must show, that you get a reference between your Thread and your form Controls. Otherwise you change the Controls of the Thread handled window (which you don't see).

Try to write Methods or Functions with `By Ref` parameter, to share your controls.